# Why does this book have Indian version and is there anything more interesting in USA version ?

Tags: discussion

I am finding a good book about aircraft and had found this one:
[image]

But I have few questions: Why does it have Idian version ? the texts in red circle are: "For sale in India, Pakistan, Nepal, Bangladesh, Sri Lanka and Bhutan only."
This book is written by an American, why couldn't they just pass it to other countries for sale ? Is there anything else in USA version ? Is there something relevant to politics here or just the language things, in order to help Indians reading more easily.

Comment: This probably should have been asked in the main site, not on "Aviation Meta".  Regardless, the question here is more about the publisher, and has little to do specifically with aviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many books, not just aviation books, have international versions, which you can learn about here: https://www.thetextbookguru.com/2011/04/20/international-textbook-editions-a-cheaper-alternative-2/   I checked several sellers online (like at Abebooks) and they claim the international version is 100% identical for this book.